# How do C++ programs work?

Tags: c++

To make my question more clear, I'd like to mention the reason for the question:-

1. I want to know if my program will be
   OS-dependent. For example, I thought
   C++ was OS-independent; Now I know
   if I program in Visual C++, my
   programs will be Windows dependent.
   So, I would like to know how to make
   sure my program isn't OS-dependent.
2. I want to know what how the thing
   works in general to be comfortable
   when programming. (It helps to know
   what happens when you include a
   header file.)
3. Maybe I can optimize my programs
   with just knowing how the thing
   works, without having to read a book
   on optimization and consume time on
   optimization rather than
   development.

I know there are books on how compilers work. But I'm not interested in this, I'm only interested in knowing the phases programs go through to get a fully working program for the reasons I've previously mentioned. Maybe there are core phases and optional/IDE dependent phases; if this is true, I would like to know both.

EDIT: Thank you very much for the answers. I got what I wanted to know, but I will open 2 other questions for more specific info.

Comment: 3) I don't think you should worry about optimizing at this point. 2) Perhaps reading a book would be a good start (not on compilers, but on C++ the language); Stroustrup's reference book is certainly a fine read and should get you right to the point. 1) If you only stick to the standard language and library, you ought to be fairly portable, but that limits you essentially to console applications. Anything beyond that will depend on a particular framework you choose.

Comment: 1) Have a look at [this question on C++ / portability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525177/program-portability)

Comment: Note to no. 3: Unless you're talking about broad scalability/computational complexity (Big O etc.) issues, don't bother to try. Whether or not this exact code will be compiled to this or that machine code and which one will execute faster depends on so many details - many of which you can't possibly know - that you might as well be guessing. Profiling/benchmarking is really the only way to measure performance impacts, and even those are easily messed up, especially when the numbers are rather small. To top it off, such differences rarely matter in many businesses.

Comment: 3) Not really an issue to me right now. 2) I'm reading Primer C++, the author mentions that including a header will include the prototypes of a file, but I don't understand why the prototype is included while definition isn't there; that's why I mentioned this point. 1) Will the framework be integrated in my program and be small? or will it be something like C#'s .net framework?

Comment: ad 1) you haven't given us _any_ specifics -- it depends entirely on what you want and need. For a pure console calculator, for instance, you need almost nothing. For networking and filesystem stuff, you might need something like POSIX, or the portable Boost. Do you want game graphics? SDL and Allegro are widely available. Desktop UIs? Maybe Qt. In general, if you really want portability, it might pay to pick a suitable framework that's already been ported widely, and for many genres of programs there are such frameworks (like Qt or SDL) which open up a wide set of platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++, the language is OS and architecture independent. The compiled executable file, however, is OS dependent. If you don't use Visual C++ specific features or any "syntax bugs" associated with it, I am pretty sure your program can run on other platforms once you compile it there.

As to your question how C++ works, I wonder if you know assembly language of any architecture. Translation from C++ to assembly is very straightforward for human (unoptimized of course), and that's how C++ programs work: they become instructions that the machine can directly run. But in reality, the compiler often get your code optimized for register usage, cache usage, branch prediction etc.

You don't get your code *much* faster if you depend on this level of optimization. Design better algorithms is what you should really work on.

Answer (score 4):

C++, including its standard library, is platform independent. If you write code in pure C++, then the code will be portable.

However, the C++ standard library is not as large as say the Java or Python standard libraries. Therefore, to write real applications, you usually need various 3rd party libraries. These may or may not be platform independent. Good platform independent 3rd party libraries that will meet a lot of your needs are Boost and Qt.

Comment: Let's reinforce that point: The C++ standard library is a _library_, not a _framework_. It has tons and tons of really clever parts for general computing needs, all of which it usually implements better than most people probably could at gunpoint and many of which you'll never need. But it's not a framework for writing applications.

Answer (score 1):

1. C++ is a standard, therefore it’s technology independent. Things get complex once you start using libraries, as not all libraries are available everywhere. Same goes for relying on language extensions and non-standard behaviour.
2. Too complex to be answered in current form. What exactly do you want to know? Wouldn’t it be better to create a separate question?
3. Optimization is harder than you think. It can be said that algorithmic optimization yields best results – if you choose a dumb algorithm, your language skills won’t help you however you try.

Answer (score 1):

C++ *is* OS independent, but you have to [compile it for each system you plan to use it on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_compile_anywhere). There is however libraries and stuff that are OS dependent, for instance [Winapi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) is Windows dependent.

Check out the standard libraries, for instance at [cplusplus](http://cplusplus.com/reference/) or look at [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) for that matter. There you have OS independent code.